# Rename files with wildcards

Tags: command-line, bash, batch-rename

I have checked the other answers but didn't find anything matches with my case. Question is simple. How can I do the following:

```
rename *A*X*.csv *A*Y*.csv
```

I know that the above line is in the Windows style but I think you got what I want. So all the files which include `A` before `X` is changed to `*A*Y*.csv` Because in my case I also have files with `*B*X*.csv` format and I don't want them to be changed.

An example:

```
myfileAisblablaXblabla.csv => myfileAisblablaYblabla.csv
```

And I have to say that there are lots of these kind of files in my case, so I need a **batch** solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rename could substitute character in the file name like sed sintax working for you should be (**test it before run**):

```
rename s/X/Y *A*X*.csv
```

Comment: You should single-quote the substitution pattern, terminate the replacement and make use of `-n` option: `rename -n 's/X/Y/' *A*X*.csv`

Comment: @RoVo -n option of rename is --nono for simulate the action but do not apply.